# express.cookieSession breaks session.destroy

Tags: session, cookies, express

Here's what my Express app config looks like:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.cookieSession({secret: conf.sessionSecret}));
app.use(express.session({secret: conf.sessionSecret}));

app.use(app.router);
```

Whenever I do this:

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res)
    {
        res.clearCookie('userId');
        req.session.destroy();
        res.redirect('/login');
    });
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'destroy'.
```

Taking out app.use(express.cookieSession()); fixes it. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [express.cookieSession](http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession), set:

```
req.session = null;
```